# downloading cctv video or live video

Tags: data-request, real-time, video

Is it possible to download long CCTV footage, or even better streaming it live? So if you want for example to write a program that recognizes objects from a video that would be possible.

Long CCTV videos are needed in order to develop the prototype. Live streaming is preferred in order to determine the efficiency of the algorithm in real time.

It would be nice if the cctv videos are categorized, cctv for a business, cctv for the highway, cctv of people, cctv of cars, etc.

So it would be nice if I can pick the location of the cctv and what it is filming for the most part. The data should be free or for a negligible price. It

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my comment, you can use live webcam feeds instead of official CCTV. Or even live youtube streams.

Consider using [insecam.org](https://www.insecam.org/) as your source. License unknown.

> The world biggest directory of online surveillance security cameras. Select a country to watch live street, traffic, parking, office, road, beach, earth online webcams. Now you can search live web cams around the world. You can find here Axis, Panasonic, Linksys, Sony, TPLink, Foscam and a lot of other network video cams available online without a password.